# Converting NSMutableArray to Array of custom objects in sudzc

Tags: cocoa, casting, sudzc

I am using SUDZC to get data from a web service. The generated code looks like this:

```
// Do something with the NSMutableArray* result
NSMutableArray* result = (NSMutableArray*)value;
```

I can see that there is a response when I called the web service but the result in the statement above is empty.

In the generated classes I can find methods to serialize the objects but are there also functions to do the deserialization?

When I get this fixed...  how can I convert the NSMutableArray to a array of my custom types generated by sudzc?

I could do something like this now:

```
for(id obj in result)
{
    Ta *ta = [[Task alloc] init];
    ta.desc = [obj DESC];
    ta.begin = [obj BEGIN];
    ta.ende = [obj ENDE];
    ta.longtext = [obj TEXT];
    [self.tas addObject:(ta)];
}
```

But is this the normal way or how should this be solved within SUDZC (because it already generated some classes for this)? How to cast the result into a list of custom objects?

Answer (score 2):

sudzc seems just return the first element in the handler, so the only thing you need to do is casting like this:
Ta *ta = (Ta *)result